# Issue with neuralnetwork_turial.lua with data preprocessing

Tags: lua, mnist, torch

I have installed the [torch deep learning module](https://github.com/nicholas-leonard/dp) by first `git clone`-ing and later using `luarocks make` and the installation was succussful. The `require 'dp'` works well in the torch prompt.

But when I try to execute the [neuralnetwork_tutorial.lua](https://github.com/nicholas-leonard/dp/blob/master/examples/neuralnetwork_tutorial.lua)(`th neuralnetwork_tutorial.lua`), it throws the following errors.

```
Tanny @neuralnetwork_tutorial.lua: About to initiate: datasource = dp.Mnist{input_preprocess = dp.Standardize()}
Tanny @/home/ubuntu/binaries/torches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/dp/preprocess/standardize.lua: Marked presence!!!
Tanny @/home/ubuntu/binaries/torches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/dp/torch/File.lua says: @177 typeidx=  3
Tanny @/home/ubuntu/binaries/torches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/dp/torch/File.lua says: @177 typeidx=  1
Tanny @/home/ubuntu/binaries/torches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/dp/torch/File.lua says: @177 typeidx=  4
Tanny @/home/ubuntu/binaries/torches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/dp/torch/File.lua says: @177 typeidx=  0
Tanny @/home/ubuntu/binaries/torches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/dp/torch/File.lua says: @177 typeidx=  28
Tanny @/home/ubuntu/binaries/torches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/dp/torch/File.lua says: @259 typeidx=  28
/home/ubuntu/binaries/torches/torch/install/bin/luajit: ...aries/torches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/File.lua:260: unknown object
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        ...aries/torches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/File.lua:260: in function 'readObject'
        ...aries/torches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/File.lua:252: in function 'readObject'
        ...aries/torches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/File.lua:277: in function 'loadData'
        ...es/torches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/dp/data/mnist.lua:74: in function 'loadTrainValid'
        ...es/torches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/dp/data/mnist.lua:61: in function '__init'
        ...aries/torches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:50: in function <...aries/torches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:46>
        [C]: in function 'Mnist'
        neuralnetwork_tutorial.lua:16: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'dofile'
        ...ches/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:131: in main chunk
        [C]: at 0x0804d650
```

I put some `print` statements in those scripts to understand the flow. I happen to notice that in [File.lua](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/File.lua) the first step after getting the object is to determine the type of the object; of which 8 have been declared. The types have been declared through 0 to 7, 0 being `TYPE_NIL`. However the code fails, as it detects a type 28(??).

Kindly any help where I am going wrong? Or where to look into to find the issue?

P.S.: The script downloads the data on its own, however due to certain standard corporate proxy setting issues, it could not download. Therefore, I personally downloaded the data [MNIST](https://stife076.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/mnist2.zip) and stored it in the specific data directory. If this could be a clue??

Comment: me too facing the same issue, even the `Mnist` data is auto downloaded by script

Comment: @jerith2: hmm probably the dataset is itself corrupted...working with the notMNIST dataset, facing some memory related issues currently, will sort out and let you know.
Before that if you reach any conclusion with any dataset, do let me know.

Comment: The dp.Mnist DataSource was just updated to use a the ascii format instead of binary. Hoping this solves your issue. Reinstall dp : sudo luarocks install dp and try the script again. To download manually : wget https://stife076.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/mnist4.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it was a bug in the code (serialized MNIST wasn't cross-platform). Fixed by serializing dataset using ascii format instead of binary.

Comment: Hey, one more help needed, would you mind answering this question ragarding [prediction using torch neural-network model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28806203/how-to-predict-using-model-generated-by-torch)