# How to predict using model generated by Torch?

Tags: lua, neural-network, deep-learning, torch

I have executed the [neuralnetwork_tutorial.lua](https://github.com/nicholas-leonard/dp/blob/master/examples/neuralnetwork_tutorial.lua). Now that I have the model, I would like to test it with some of my own handwritten images. But I have tried many ways by storing the weights, and now by storing the complete model using [torch save and load methods](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/serialization.md).

However now that I try to predict my own handwritten images(converted to 28X28 DoubleTensor) using `model:forward(testImageTensor)`

```
...ches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/dp/model/sequential.lua:30: attempt to index local 'carry' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        ...ches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/dp/model/sequential.lua:30: in function '_forward'
        ...s/torches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/dp/model/model.lua:60: in function 'forward'
        [string "model:forward(testImageTensor)"]:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
        ...aries/torches/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:588: in function 'repl'
        ...ches/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:185: in main chunk
        [C]: at 0x0804d650
```

Comment: In torch it is straight forward, just like how you're trying to do it. This seems to be a side-effect of using the "dp" package. Maybe the authors of "dp" can help.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.

One. Use the encapsulated [nn.Module](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/module.md#module) to forward your [torch.Tensor](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor):

```
mlp2 = mlp:toModule(datasource:trainSet():sub(1,2))
input = testImageTensor:view(1, 1, 32, 32)
output = mlp2:forward(input)
```

Two. Encapsulate your torch.Tensor into a [dp.ImageView](http://dp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/view/index.html#dp.ImageView) and forward that through your [dp.Model](http://dp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/model/index.html#dp.Model) :

```
inputView = dp.ImageView('bchw', testImageTensor:view(1, 1, 32, 32))
outputView = mlp:forward(inputView, dp.Carry{nSample=1})
output = outputView:forward('b')
```